# Use parameters for MySqlCommand query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to insert into mysql table using this code:

```
// open connection here
this.conn.Open();

// fields from post request
var email = Request.Form["email"];  
var password = Request.Form["password"];

string sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO mytable(col1, col2) values(?email, ?password)";
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(sqlInsert, this.conn);
cmd1.Parameters.Add("?email", email);
cmd1.Parameters.Add("?password", password);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

here: `cmd1.Parameters.Add("?email", email);` I am getting  error:

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.mysqlDBType'

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the [`Add`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/Overload_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameterCollection_Add.htm) method the wrong way.

It should be `cmd1.Parameters.Add("?email", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = email;`
(You can choose another overload if you want to, but this is the easiest to use most of the times.)

Note: I'm guessing the data type of `email` is `VarString`.

Comment: Or he can use `AddWitheValue` variant

Comment: @styx `AddWithValue` means that the MySql driver must infer the actual data type of the parameter supplied - which could be dangerous as it may lead to exceptions or even worst - wrong data. For more information, [read this.](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @ZoharPeled here the client is SqlClient, which I have seen works fine while it tries to figure out the underlying type especially common data type like string, infact micro orm like Dapper also does it without an issue

Comment: @MrinalKamboj AddWithValue works find on many ADO.Net client implementations... until it doesn't. I wouldn't count on it "working fine" when I know for a fact that sometimes it doesn't, and there's a perfectly easy and safer way to send parameters to the database. The couple of extra key strokes are totally worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to convert your string parameter to MySQL Db type parameter, I usually create a function in code like this:

```
protected DbParameter GetParameter(string parameterName, object parameterValue)
        {
            DbParameter parameterObject = new MySqlParameter(parameterName, 
            parameterValue ?? DBNull.Value);

            //this defines if it is an input or output parameter
            // you can also have output paramters
            parameterObject.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            return parameterObject;
        }
```

and call it int our code like this:

```
       var somevariable = "somevalue";

        var parameters = new List<DbParameter>
        {
            base.GetParameter("parametermnamehere", somevariable),
        };
```

Simple and Clean, hope it helps